# What is the scalar polynomial of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm familiar with characteristic polynomials. $\det(A-\lambda I) = p(\lambda) = (\lambda_1 - \lambda)(\lambda_2 - \lambda)\dots(\lambda_n- \lambda)$

The question says to show that if $g(x)$ is a scalar polynomial and $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_n$ then the eigenvalues of $g(A)$ are $g(\lambda_1), g(\lambda_2), \dots, g(\lambda_n)$.

I think this will be  a straighforward question after I understand what it means to put put a linear transformation $A$ into a function $g(\cdot)$ but that operation doesn't seem defined...

Comment: If $g(x) = x^3+x^2+x+1$ then $g(A)=A^3+A^2+A+I$, for example.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_polynomial